# Specifying git revision of submodule hosted in subversion?

Tags: svn, git

We currently have a project hosted in a subversion repo that points to an external dependency.  We would like to make this git friendly, as we have a git mirror setup.

I'm able to set up a submodule for the external via git, but don't see a way to specify the specific revision the submodule should point to via a svn-compatible patch.  The goal would be to patch the svn project in such a way that the submodule is recognized and can be pulled in through Ant.  The git project in the patch sets a property on the external folder that, of course, subversion doesn't understand.

Am I missing something simple, or is this a bridge too far in svn-git land? The specifics, patch and all, [are here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HCATALOG-14).

Comment: judging from the number of reactions, a bridge too far, indeed